# Getting the name of the folder and comparing to integer in bash

Tags: bash, date, directory

Ok, so what I'm trying to do is, all my backup folders are named dates 03-07-13.  So I'm trying to select the day, and if it's greater than or equal to 7 days old, it will delete. This is what I have so far, but it's not working.

```
DATE=$(date +"%d")

for i in /media/backupdrive/*; do
    DAY=${i:22:2}
    if [ "$DAY" -ge "7" ]
    then
        echo "day greater than 7";
    fi
done
```

the 22:2 cuts off the /media/backupdrive/00-

00 represents the month

Right now It's just checking if it's greater than 7, if it is, it prints it out.

EDIT: The problem was resolved. I want to thank you all for helping a bash beginner. Thank you again!

Comment: ...so what's your question?

Comment: Sorry didn't share that. IT says "interger expression expected on the if statement line. I need to make the DAY variable an integer to compare it to the current day and if it's greater than or equal to 7.

Comment: If you do `echo $DAY;` inside your loop, what's the value?

Comment: It will print out 06 and 07. The two folders in the /backupdrive/ directory are 03-06-13 and 03-07-13

Comment: http://puu.sh/2dH5X There a screenshot of the output.  22 works for me, but this is the error it's giving me on the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per a screenshot given in a comment, your actual code uses the following:

```
DAY=${i:22:2}
if [ "$day" -ge "7" ]
```

Emphasis on the capitalization-differences between `DAY` and `$day`. When this runs, it's trying to compare an empty-string to a string (or "numbers" via the `-ge`) and *this* will cause the error you're receiving.

Try updating your `if` statement to use the uppercase version:

```
if [ "$DAY" -ge "7" ]
```

Comment: You guys have no idea how much trouble I've had with this. Thanks for helping a beginner progress!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to delete files that are older than 7 days. The `find` command can find those files for you, and optionally delete them:

```
find /media/backupdrive -mtime +7         # Files that are older than 7 days
find /media/backupdrive -mtime +7 -delete # ... and delete them
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'DAY' variable opens you up to "just rolled over" issues.

Some alternatives:

- change the folder format so that it is more descriptive.
- add a meta file in each folder that gives a time value that is easier to parse and work with.
- have an index for the backup folders containing said data.

The time format I generally use incorporates the following:

```
   [epoch seconds]-[YYYY][MM][DD]-[HH]:[MM]:[SS]
```

This lets you do things like asking for backups that are 7 days old from right now. You would do the math against the epoch seconds, which avoids the confusion of days rolling over.

Basically, the epoch seconds is for making time calcs easier. The other time stamp bits makes it human readable. The ordering makes it so that it sorts correctly in a folder listing.

EDIT:

In the event your backup path ever changes:

```
  DAYtmp=${i: -8:5}
  DAY=${DAYtmp: -2}
```

This will yield the DAY from the folder name if the parent paths change in length.